# Is there a way union two separate meshes with two separate material

Tags: modeling, mesh, materials, modifiers, objects

I used the skin wrap modifier to create gloves and added material to them, and then added a different material to the second mesh. However, when I try to use the union tool, one of the materials disappears and it just defaults to the other material or the object just disappears too. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Add the materials used to the modified mesh, even if in "empty" slots.  Boolean will try to assign faces appropriate materials, but for that to happen, the modified object needs to have those materials associated with it.

Comment: At first, I was trying to copy and paste the mat. But then I realized that I was dumb and there was a drop-down, thank you so much for your help.